# Случайный массив без повторений! Как реализовать на Basic 6 ???

Tags: массивы, visual-basic

Всем привет! Только начал изучать бейсик. Немогу сообразить как заполнить массив случайными числами без повторений. Прошу подсказать... Я могу заполнить массив случайно, но там иногда повторяються числа, а мне этого не надо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim arr(0 To 10) As Long
Dim a(0 To 10000) As Long
Dim n As Integer

Private Sub Command1_Click()
n = 10
For i = 0 To n
Dim tmp As Long
tmp = Rnd * 1001
Do
tmp = Rnd * 1001
Loop Until a(i) = a(tmp)
arr(i) = tmp
a(i) = 1
Print arr(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Как то так, по моему!

Answer (score 0):

Проверять, а нет ли числа в коллекции и если есть, генерировать снова. Генератор псевдослучайных чисел там не ахти какой на самом деле, так что изощряются как могут, например, кто-то, помню, делал так (если вещественные числа):

```
(Rnd() + Rnd() + Rnd()) / 3
```

Ну и в том же духе, но проверять на уже существующее число придётся